# Is it possible to get a standard deviation of a data set compared to a target value?

Tags: data-visualization, standard-deviation

I am working on defining performance measures for manufacturing and one of the performance measures I am working on has to do with the production time. Basically, the company sends releases different work orders to produce multiple sub-assemblies, often in different quantities. One of the goals of the company is to reduce the production time. So for a given period, let's say one month, a performance measure is defined as follows:

([Total actual production time] - [total targeted production time]) / [total targeted production time]

This measure will show if you, overall, lower the production time of all work orders. Now am I also interested to see how the spread is of the dataset, and especially for the work orders with actual production time exceeding targeted production time. Let's take data set:

```
Work order    Actual (hrs)  Target (hrs)   Difference (hrs)
1             13            11             +2
2             17            16             +1
3             10            12             -2

Average       13.3          13
Overall %difference = (13.3 - 13)/13 = 2.3%
```

The standard deviation of the actual hours will not say anything because different work orders have different target times. The difference column indicates that the total extra time on work orders that exceed target time is 3 hours and the total time spend less on work orders that do not exceed target time is 2 hours.

I've tried a different way of approaching this by calculating the overall %difference like above (the 2.3%) which says that you spend on average 2.3% more on work orders than the target hours, and I calculated the overall %difference of hours of the work order that exceed target time with the target times of those work orders. So in this example:

[Total extra hours]/[total targeted hours] = (2+1)/(16+11)=9%

Meaning that of the work order that exceed target time, people spend on average 9% more time. I am interested to see if this could be done in another way that would say more.

My question now is: Is it possible to calculate a standard deviation of the actual hours compared to the targeted hours? And would it also be possible to calculate separate sort of deviation for the work orders with higher production time and work orders with lower production time than target? And how could this be best visualized?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the standard deviation of your fourth column? Of course, then you should represent the mean hours exceeded rather than a percentage (mean of column 4). But that seems to me the more direct way of relating the amount over.

Comment: That could be an approach, but it would then say nothing about how much it differs from the targeted production hours. If the targeted production hours for WOs that take longer than the targeted hours are 100 and of the difference is 20 (thus 20%) would be more significant than if targeted hours were a 1000 and difference is 20 (thus 2%). But maybe that is just a choice of choosing the measure. Would calculating the standard deviation for a data set with non-normal distribution actually still be a useful indicator?

Comment: Your standard deviation question, taken just as it is, has the answer yes. The more complicated answer is that it doesn't necessarily have all of the same properties. As to your percentage overage idea, if you have a large range of target hours then I suggest your attempt to make them all comparable with percentage doesn't solve all of your problems either. Nevertheless, it's a reasonable metric you can also take the SD of. And some percentages (like this one that isn't bounded by 100 or 0) can be normally distributed.

Comment: I guess the short answer is, if you think the percentages are sufficient for your situation just take the SD of them.

Comment: Thank you very much John for your time and insight. I will try out some different calculations with different data and will see what metric would provide me the right insight. Have a good holiday!